# Mysql fetch() returns FALSE

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have currently a problem on streaming results from a mysql table. This table has more than 10,000,000 rows. And the structure

> ID, IndexField1, Data1

With Primaryindex on ID and Index on IndexField1.

In PHP I tied to stream parts of the data (about 7 Mio) to calculate and verify some parts. For this reason I hava a callback which is been called for every single response.

```
public function streamForIndexedColumn(int $columnId, callable $callback){
$stmt = NULL;
$sql = "SELECT id, indexedField, data1 FROm myTable WHERE indexedField1 = ?;";
if (! ($stmt = $this->mysqlConn->prepare ( $sql ))) {
   throw new Exception("ERROR");
}
try {
    if (! $stmt->bind_param ( "i", $columnId)) {
       throw new Exception( "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error );
    }
    $item = new Item ();
    if (!$stmt->bind_result($item->id,$item->indexfield1,$item->data1)) {
            throw new Exception( "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error );
    }

    if (! $stmt->execute ()) {
        throw new Exception("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error );
    }
    $cnt = 0;
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $cnt++;
        $callback($cnt, $item);
    }
    if ($row ===FALSE){
        throw new Exception("MySQL Error: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error );
    } finally{
        $stmt->close ();
    }
}
```

This runs sometimes for several hours. Sometimes it is running, sometimes it is failing with message "MySQL Error: (0) "

Are I am getting the error reason in a wrong way? Are there any configurable Limits on the server or client which may produce this error?

I am using Mysql 5.17.19 and PHP 7.0.29.

Comment: As a side node: When it is failing it is failing after some hours (so after processing items)

Comment: Your while loop fetches all of the rows until `$row` returns false, then it will exit and hit the if check. The if check is not necessary, so remove it.

Comment: does mysqli have `fetch()` ?

Comment: No: According to documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) it is returning FALSE in case of Errors. Thats why I checked for the type as well. In case of no more data it is returning NULL. In some cases it is not failing. So I don't think that the implementation is wrong, but I cannot find any example for error handling for this method

Comment: When I run my script in CLI I got another warning: PHP Warning:  "Empty row packet body"

Answer (score 0):

The exception in `$row === FALSE` will always be thrown because after it fetches all rows, `$row` will be false.

`$stmt->errno` will return 0 because (Quoted from the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php)
Returns the error number from the last MySQL function, or 0 (zero) if no error occurred.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysqli but I'd say that [mysqli_stmt::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns `null` when done.

Comment: Thanks, Daan, for your comment but Alvaro is right: From the documentation it is returning FALSE in case of errors. Sometimes(!) it is fine and it is returning me the right result, so I don't think that it is an implementation error. Maybe some limits on querying. But even this time is different from time to time.